# After adding a custom css, it does not render in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I create template name is Demo in magento2.

in default_heade_blocks.xml i use

```
<link src="css/custom.css"  media="all" />
```

but it not render when i view-source.
I not found it in **pub/static/../demo/css** folder.
I tried

Comment: have u created a new theme ?

Comment: yes i created theme name is 'demo'.

Comment: give me your css file path

Comment: this is file path: app\design\frontend\Magento\xanka\web\css\custom.css

Answer (score 0):

Try this commands in CLI.

1) `php bin/magento cache:flush`

2) `sudo php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

if not works then clear contend of `\pub\static\` excluding .htaccess manually.

**Note:** after applying the new theme most of the link should serve form your theme directory verify it from source code.

If not so then follow http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html  to check for missing step.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I tried remove all  cache and pub/static/ except .htaccess  then i run php \ bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy. But it not render file custom.css
I create theme like document in magento2.

Comment: is other content are serving from Demo